# Matplotlib does not show figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a python beginner and am learning the `matplotlib` now. However, when I try to run the code, the plot does not show up. My code is just simple:

```
import matplot.pyplot as pyt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
plt.show
```

I have installed `matplotlib` in cmd by command and it said "Successfully installed matplotlib-3.2.1"

Comment: You need parenthesis to call show. Try plt.show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.show` is not a function. It should be `plt.show()`

Comment: Oh it works. Turns out it was a dumb question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `plt.show` is actually a function ! The point is to call it !